# Add cookie to axios interceptor request handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm configuring Axios to always make a request with header Authorization with a value which is in user cookie.
My code:

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
import {useCookies} from "react-cookie";
const [cookies] = useCookies(["myToken"]);

const customAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost/storeApi/',
    timeout: 10000,
});

const requestHandler = (request: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${cookies.jwtToken}`;
    return request;
};

customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => requestHandler(request)
);

export default customAxios;
```

But I have an error:

```
 Line 3:19:  React Hook "useCookies" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: Hooks can only be called inside of a functional react component.  [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: Ok, so can you show code example how can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a React Hook, you can't use `useCookies` outside a React component function: to access a cookie, you'll need to read it from `document.cookie`, or install another package, like [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie).

If you're only using the one cookie, you can probably get away by using [w3School's cookie example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp#:%7E:text=a%20cookie%20value-,A%20Function%20to%20Set%20a%20Cookie,-First%2C%20we%20create), (which I've turned into an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookied)):

> ```js
> function getCookie(cname) {
>   let name = cname + "=";
>   let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
>   let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
>   for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
>     let c = ca[i];
>     while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
>       c = c.substring(1);
>     }
>     if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
>       return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
>     }
>   }
>   return "";
> }
> ```

Then just do:

```js
const cookie: string = getCookie('myToken');
```

Comment: Is there a repo for the 'cookied' package you made? Want to do a pull request to add delete cookie function

Comment: @ZakMicallef It's a private repo owned by my previous employer, unfortunately.